# Newbie problems with Persistent

Tags: sqlite, haskell, persistent, yesod

So I am planing to use Persistent 0.9.0.1 with Sqlite, and I am going through the tutorial: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent

The simple snippet with insert and query fails to compile:

```
-- START
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TypeFamilies, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, TemplateHaskell,
             OverloadedStrings, GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkSave "entityDefs"] [persist|
Person
    name String
    age Int
|]

main = withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ runSqlConn $ do
    runMigration $ migrate entityDefs (undefined :: Person) -- this line added: that's it!
    michaelId <- insert $ Person "Michael" 26
    michael <- get michaelId
    liftIO $ print michael
-- STOP
```

Dumping splices shows no promised `Eq`, `Show` instances for generated Person, strange:

```
data PersonGeneric (backend :: (* -> *) -> * -> *)
    = Person {personName :: String, personAge :: Int}
type Person =
    PersonGeneric Database.Persist.GenericSql.Raw.SqlPersist
```

I hack it like this:

```
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ "name: " ++ (personName $ fromJust michael) ++ ", age: " ++ (show $ personAge $ fromJust michael)
```

And then insert fails to get the primary key back from Sqlite:

```
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "person"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"age" INTEGER NOT NULL)
proto: Pattern match failure in do expression at Database/Persist/GenericSql.hs:109:25-45
```

Any ideas?  Does Persistent work with Sqlite?

Comment: Could you include the error message? Is it "No instance for `(Show Person)`"?

Comment: @hammar Yes, it was, fixed it with Michael's help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a change from version 0.8 to 0.9 where we no longer include `Eq` and `Show` instances by default. To add them in, add the following line underneath `age Int`:

```
deriving Show Eq
```

The book is still targeted at version 0.10 of Yesod, but I'll try to update it in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the first problem that I hacked around.  The pattern match error in GenericSql.hs still remains.  Should I file a bug on Github for that?

Comment: I saw a comment along the same lines in an email. It *might* be caused by version 0.4.1 of conduit. I released a patch in version 0.4.1.1. Can you try upgrading to that version and see if it resolves the issue?

Comment: Glad it worked. For future use, I'd recommend sticking to yesod-platform versions of packages when possible, as they are tested together and (at least should) always work properly.